# Locking Down a Port-Forwarding User

Tags: linux

I have the need to tunnel/forward a port over SSH. While I'm familiar with the ins and outs of doing this, I'd like to lock down the user so they effectively have no shell, rather just a process that accepts no input/output and allows a persistent SSH connection and port forwarding.

Is there a shell binary which accomplishes this? I could possibly do something like this in Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec watch -n 1 date
```

And set that Bash file as the shell for that user. I imagine there may be security pitfalls in doing this.

Is there a Unix/Linux binary that provides this service?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/56566/ssh-tunneling-only-access

Comment: Whatever shell you use, without extreme caution, you risk that the user finds a way to escape it. Instead use the sshd config option `Match` to match on the relevant user(s) and provide in it `DenyUsers *` plus `AllowTcpForwarding yes` (you can also make sure that outside the Match clause you deny everything, based on your needs).

Comment: @Joe that can be an answer.

Comment: Actually I'm not seeing that work. I might have to try Patrick's solution.